# Protobuf Comparison field name vs generic fieldname, value

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have protobuf where there are multiple fields like

temperature, CPU, memory etc.

Is it better to define it in generic way eg: B or specific  eg:A

```
messsage Sensor {
    uint32 temperature = 1;
    uint32 cpu = 2;
    uint32 mem = 3;
}
```

eg: B

```
message Sensor {
    repeated FieldValues = 1; // might be map also
}

message FieldValues {
    string name = 1;
    uint64 = 2;  // To accomodate all the ranges(int/long/double)
}
```

For performance    A

For extensibility(Adding additional fields) B

Is there any other pros/cons ?

Answer (score 1):

Protobufs has you covered with extensibility of `A` because you can evolve the `message` by adding (!) fields.

I think you should (generally!) prefer to use the abstraction that is most intuitive|understandable and (generally!) prefer to leave optimization to the machines.

That said, there are differences between `A` and `B`.

`A` always includes `temperature`, `cpu` and `mem` which, if modeling e.g. a computer, each of these will always have a value. But, if you don't measure e.g. the `temperature`, you will need to have logic that e.g. defines a `0` temperature as representing "not recorded".

`A` enables you to (slightly more easily) represent different value types (you could have float, enum values too).

`B` enables you to record a variable set of values. And (unlike `A`), the absence of a value is a useful fact that no value was recorded.

Depending upon your encoding choice `repeated` or `map`, you will receive (depending on your language(s) of choice) an (ordered) list|array|slice or a map. If you choose `repeated`, finding individual values requires enumerating (half of the) slice to find the value.